# Create a Loop that Randomly Populates a collection of Binary DataFrames matrices- Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, random, iteration

I need to create a collection of DataFrames, randomly populated with 0's and 1's.  I want to do this iteratively.

I create one such DataFrame by the following code:

```
     bin1=np.random.rand(4,4)
     bin1_df=pd.DataFrame(bin1)
     binx1_df=(bin1_df==bin1_df.max()).astype(int)
```

This results look like the following (note, the 0's and 1's are randomly generated, only one '1' in each column):

```
0   0 0 0 1
1   1 0 0 0
2   0 1 0 0
3   0 0 1 0
```

How can I create a collection of these, say, for example, four sets, iteratively (via a loop or other)?

I have tried by first creating the specified list of DataFrames, and then populating with the 'random' function, but it does not to work -- like the following:

```
bins = ['bin1_df', 'bin2_df', 'bin3_df', 'bin4_df']
binsx = ['binx1_df', 'binx2_df', 'binx3_df', 'binx4_df']

for eachBin in bins:
  for eachBinx in binsx:
      vars()[eachBin]=np.random.rand(4,4)
      vars()[eachBin]=pd.DataFrame()
      vars()[eachBinx]=([eachBin]==[eachBin].max()).astype(int)
```

I don't really know where to begin in combining the creation of the DataFrame with the random populating.  Any advice you can offer will be greatly appreciated :).

Comment: I don't get what you want? do you want to generate dataframes that have exactly one 1 at each column at a random row?

Comment: I want to generate a collection of 4x4 matrices, randomly populating 0's and 1's -- only one '1' per column.  A row can have many 1's.  so a matrix like:

Comment: You already know how to do it for one, just repeat the process with a single loop. Also don't try to assign variables dynamically, this is an anti-pattern, rather use a dictionary.

Comment: I don't know how to iterate the name of the dataFrame in the loop - like bin1_df, bin2_df, bin3_df, bin4_df....  When I try to do this dynamic referencing, I always get 'not hashable' or 'type' or 'syntax' errors.

Comment: You should never try to generate variables dynamically. Just create a function that outputs unnamed bin and binx and store them in lists. Since all your dataframes have a dummy name like binX_df there is really no point in having a name. Being in a list is much easier to handle.

Comment: Something like `N = 4 ; bins = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4)) for _ in range(N)] ; binsX = [(b==b.max()).astype(int) for b in bins]`.

Comment: Or as tuples in a single list: `N = 4 ; bins = [((b:=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4))), (b==b.max()).astype(int)) for _ in range(N)]`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, it seems you want something like:

```
from numpy.random import default_rng

rng = default_rng()

bins = []
for _ in range(4):
    bin = rng.choice(16, size=(4,4), replace=False)
    bins.append(pd.DataFrame((bin == bin.max(axis=0)).astype(int)))
```

Sample Output:

```
[
   0  1  2  3
0  0  0  0  0
1  1  0  1  0
2  0  1  0  1
3  0  0  0  0,

   0  1  2  3
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  0
2  0  1  0  0
3  0  0  0  1,

   0  1  2  3
0  1  0  1  0
1  0  0  0  1
2  0  0  0  0
3  0  1  0  0,

   0  1  2  3
0  0  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0
2  1  0  0  0
3  0  0  1  1
]
```

Comment: What if I want to refer to each matrix independently now (for example - I might want to manipulate the first one, and not the others).  In other words, I want to be able to work with these as matrix1_df, matrix2_df, matrix3_df, matrix4_df

Comment: Growing a list with `+` has a quadratic behavior, you really shouldn't do that ;)

Comment: You can access them individually as `bins[0]`, `bins[1]` etc.

Comment: @mozway long day. fixed

Comment: @user23317935 note that your random code could possibly produce two identical values in a bin, which could then give you more than one `1` in a column. I've edited my answer with a more robust solution.